# How can I test the http.NewRequest in Go?

Tags: testing, go

I am mostly familiar with testing in Go, but struggling to find a way to test the following function:

```
func postJson(url string, jsonData []byte) error {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    resp.Body.Close()
    return nil
}
```

I want to check that the request has correct post data with the right headers. Tried to look into [httptests](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/), but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

The [httptest.Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) has a [URL](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.URL) field, you can use that value to send your requests to, so this would be the `url` argument to your function.

Then to test whether the [http.Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) was sent with the right headers and body you can create the test server with a custom handler when calling [httptest.NewServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer). This handler will then be invoked by the server on each request that is sent to the url mentioned above, so your test logic should go inside this handler.

```
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Test that r is what you expect it to be
}))
defer ts.Close()

err := postJson(ts.URL+"/foo/bar", data)
```

Playground:https://play.golang.org/p/SldU4JSs911